# Meshlab: .stl file does not retain smoothing after saving

Tags: graphics, mesh, medical, meshlab

I have been trying Meshlab software for smoothing the .stl file and exporting the mesh as .wrl file. I used Laplacian smoothing (Laplacian Smooth with smoothing steps of 2, 1D boundary smooting and contangent weighting). After applying the smoothing filter, it worked nicely. Then I exported the file and saved it. However, when I open the saved file afterwards it goes back to the original un-smoothed version, each time. Same problem persists even if I export the mesh as .stl file. I am not sure if this is a bug or something else.

I don't know if I have missed anything. Do you have any idea what might the problem be?

Thanks in advance.